# Open source file manager for use with custom API - not file system

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ckeditor, azure-storage

I have a .Net MVC/Web API application which uses CK Editor as the rich text editor. I want to allow my users to upload files and use them in the rich text editor controls.

I know there are plenty of open source web file managers out there but all of the ones I have looked at rely on a file system for file storage.

My application uses Azure blob storage and each user has a container which they can upload to. I have an API which can upload files and also retrieve a list of files which are returned as JSON.

Is there any open source file manager which can be configured to work with this? I can adjust my server side API to work with whatever client I can find.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`RichFilemanager`](https://github.com/servocoder/RichFilemanager). It is highly customizable and you can implement your own [connector](https://github.com/servocoder/RichFilemanager/wiki/API) to work with Azure Blob storage.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a .Net MVC/Web API application which uses CK Editor as the rich text editor. I want to allow my users to upload files and use them in the rich text editor controls.

AFAIK, the Open Source version of CKEditor does not support **File upload and management with CKFinder**. For CKFinder 3, it supports cloud storage (Amazon, Dropbox, Azure Blob Storage, etc.). For CKFinder 3 ASP.NET Connector Azure Backend, you could refer to [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/configuration.html#configuration_options_backends_azure).

I assumed that you could leverage [Ueditor](https://github.com/fex-team/ueditor/) and modify the [controller.ashx](https://github.com/fex-team/ueditor/blob/dev-1.5.0/net/controller.ashx) from .NET backend to implement your file processing against azure blob storage by yourself.

Additionally, If you just want to provide the feature for your users to manage the uploaded files, you could use [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) and generate the SAS token against the blob container for each of your user, then the users could use the sas token via Azure Storage Explorer to manage the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `@opuscapita/filemanager`

https://github.com/OpusCapita/filemanager